# 括弧内の文字級下げ(正規表現)

Tags: 正規表現, indesign

⭐InDesign正規表現

外の全角括弧の級数はそのままで、内側の文字の級数を下げたいのですが
`（あああ）`や`（ああ（ああ）ああ）`など

```
（[^（）]*(（[^（）]*）[^（）]*)*）
```

これだと全ての全角括弧が小さくなってしまうので`（|）`も追加で設定しました。
しかしこれだと全角括弧内にある括弧も大きくなってしまいます。
外の全角括弧の級数はそのままで、中にある文字(括弧も含む)の級数を小さくするにはどのような正規表現があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 対象のデータフォーマットは何でしょうか？質問文に書かれている「(あああ)」「(ああ(ああ)ああ)」等には文字サイズの情報が含まれていません。

Comment: InDesign CC15の段落スタイル内にある正規表現を使用しています。(perl？) 外の全角括弧は13Q、中の文字は11Qにしたく、文字スタイルで登録していて、正規表現でその文字スタイルを適応させたいと考えています。

Comment: 因みに一段落最高4回(ああ(ああ)ああ)の形が出てくるとしたらどのようになりますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?<=（)(.*)(?=）)`

1行に複数回この表現が出てくるとダメですが...